# How to get this SQL query into rails (3) syntax

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a sql-Statement and I'd like to "convert" it into rails (activerecord) method calls.

This is my query

```
'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE company_id IN (SELECT company_id FROM companies_projects WHERE project_id= ? )
```

- *companies_projects* is a join table for an n:n relation of *companies* and *projects*
- *clients* belong to companies (1:n)
- *project* is an external resource and has no *has_many companies*, so I can't go from that direction
- I want to get all *clients* that belong to *companies* that belong to one *project*, so I can list them in the index-page

My models

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies_projects
  has_many :clients
  has_many :projects, :through => :companies_projects
end
```

I checked the statement in rails console and it works.

I have two problems impelementing this query.

**1. find_by_sql**

I tried this method

```
Client.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM clients WHERE company_id IN (SELECT company_id FROM companies_projects WHERE project_id= ? )',project.id)
```

But it throws an InvalidStatement Exception, MySQL Syntax Error near "?"
I also tried to put the sql and bindings into an array [sql,bind1], that works but I get an array and need an ActiveRecordRelation

**2. where**

I'm new to rails and can't figure out a valid method chain for such a query.

Could someone point me in the right direction?
I would prefer using ActiveRecord methods for the query, but I just don't know which methods to use for the nested selects.

Comment: Do you have an intermediate model CompanyProject?

Comment: Look at [joining tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Client.where(company_id: CompanyProject.where(project_id: project.id).pluck(:id))
```

Or you can use JOIN

```
Client.joins(:company_project).where('companies_projects.project_id = ?', project.id)
```

But the best solution was proposed by @arup-rakshit

Answer (score 5):

You should have following associations between your models:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  has_many :clients
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
  has_many :clients, through: :companies
end
```

Then it is simply:

```
project.clients
```

Comment: This would actually work, but I can't access the Project model, it's an external resource, so basically I have no projects.companies, just company.projects

Comment: @mrong - How do you use `project.id` in your initial query then?

Comment: I'm writing a plugin. I can use the models but don't know how to extend them, i.e. the Project model doesn't know it has many companies. SHould have made this clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have an intermediate model CompanyProject, this can be achieved with following query:

```
Client.where(:company_id => CompanyProject.where(:project_id => project_id).map(&:company_id) )
```

[Edit: made company_id a symbol)